# Installed jetpack plugin on localhost but not showing testimonials or portfolio section on dashboard

Tags: wordpress

Installed jetpack plugin on localhost but not showing testimonials or portfolio section on dashboard, using the four lite theme required jetpack plugin. or the scenario for jetpack is you have to get your site live? it didn't work for localhost? any idea?

Comment: Search a little.... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189532/how-to-run-jetpack-from-localhost

Answer (score 1):

Locate your `wp-config.php` file. Then add this code below.

```
const JETPACK_DEV_DEBUG = TRUE;
```

If code above don't work try by adding this one

```
define( 'JETPACK_DEV_DEBUG', true);
```

[Here](https://jetpack.com/2013/03/28/jetpack-dev-mode-release/) you can find the Jetpack tut dev mode.
Hope this would help.